WSO2 - EI - unable to override HTTP status code returned by Third party when its 202
I am calling a third party from my sequence, if it returns any http code other than 200, i can easily override it, but if its 202, its overriden inside the sequence but once loopback is called, the http code returned is 202 again. Any idea why?
Code used:

Solved by adding the following:
<property name="SC_ACCEPTED" value="false" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2"/>

